# Image in header, custom padding

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

First of all, sorry about the poor title, but I searched for ten minutes and couldn't find a better one..

I'm using `fancyhdr` to set some custom headers and footer in my `LaTeX` document.

I'd like to make my top left image overlap the auto-generated header line.
To be clear, I'd like the Eiffel tower to overlap the line in the picture below :

[image: Header picutre]

My current code to get this result is pretty simple, but I have no idea on how to solve my goal :

```
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo.png}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` with a negative `<len>` to drop the image as far as you want.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

In the example, the image is dropped 70% of its own height (`\height`). For help on the syntax of `\raisebox`, see [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **57 LaTeX Box commands**, p 232):

> `\raisebox{<distance>}[<height>][<depth>]{<box>}`:
>
> Raises `<box>` up by  length (down if `<distance>` negative). Makes TeX
>   think that the new box extends `<height>` above the line and `<depth>` below, for a
>   total vertical length of `<height>`+`<depth>`. Default values of `<height>` & `<depth>` =
>   actual height and depth of box in new position.